# statement after waitforseconds() not working in unity

Tags: c#, unityscript

I m new to unity and c# as well. I want to delay a function hence using `WaitForSeconds()` but my problem is that the statement after `WaitForSeconds()` is not executed and hence there is no delay shown.

Below is the code:

```
public void GameOver(){
    StartCoroutine (Load ());
    Debug.Log("loadDelay");
}

IEnumerator Load(){
    Debug.Log ("enum");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    Debug.Log("waited");            
}
```

the output on console shows:

> enum
>   loadDelay

At the same time without any delay when the `GameOver()` is called and `Debug.Log("waited");`

is not executed at all. I really don't understand the problem. Please explain if I'm doing something wrong.
Thanks
Code where `GameOver()` is called:

```
public class Collision : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject explosion;
    BgScroll bg;

    void Start () {
        bg = GetComponent<BgScroll> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
            //Debug.Log("destroyed");
            explosion.renderer.sortingLayerName = "foreground";
            Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            Destroy (gameObject);
            Debug.Log("destroyed");

            bg.GameOver();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line: "yield return new WaitForSeconds(3)" is doing exactly what it should do. What you're basically saying is: "Wait for this to wait 3 seconds then return out of the function". Due to the "return" keyword, you will never reach your "waited" output.

Comment: okay but it should then wait for 3 seconds and then return. but its not waiting which is the main problem.

Comment: @LokiSinclair No, this is how enumerators work. When you call `MoveNext` on the enumerator, it will execute the rest of the method (until either the end, or the next `yield return`/`yield break`). Unity3D exploits this behaviour to allow for asynchronous code execution (it was designed before `await` was in the language).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Unity's Documentation for WaitForSeconds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) you are doing it right. and your code works good when i tried to run it. There must be some other problem, or you might have other logs before "waited". I got output in console window as

> enum
>
> loadDelay
>
> waited

and obviously "waited" will be printed after 3 seconds if your player is running at that time.

Comment: maybe because u started the Coroutine in `void Start()` because in that case its working fine for me too but here i have declared StartCoroutine in `GameOver()` which is called by another script when the player is destroyed. Is it necessary to write `StartCoroutine()` in `void Start()` only?

Comment: No it is not required to call it from `Start()`. Can you share code where you are calling `GameOver()`